# How do I batch convert thousands of NEFs to JPEGs?

Tags: batch, jpeg, image-conversion, camera-raw

I accidentally set my camera (a Nikon D70) to shoot in NEF only and not NEF+JPEG.

Obviously, this will be a major pain when I want to go through them all. I don't envy having to wait for seconds at a time for a single picture to render.

Is there any way I can batch convert the whole set (thousands of pictures) to JPEGs?

I am running Windows 7 and Xubuntu 12.04.

Comment: You probably got a copy of View NX2 (you can download from the Nikon site) with your camera - that will batch convert and do it in a similar way to in camera conversion

Comment: On my mac, ViewNX2 crashes randomly when batch converting NEFs to JPGs. Worse, you cannot restart from where it last crashed. Also, ViewNX2 development has been stopped and Nikon has developed a new tool Capture NX-D -  I've not used it yet but I'd be cautious using it for large batch conversions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another great free tool is [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) that when combined with [plugins](http://www.irfanview.com/plugins.htm) can Batch convert from almost any format to JPG.

[Q: Can I use IrfanView on Linux?](http://www.irfanview.com/faq.htm#Q57)

A: Yes. There is no native-Linux version of IrfanView. However, you can use IrfanView in conjunction with Linux programs like WINE, Windows Linux emulators and Linux-based virtual machines. Take the ZIP version of IrfanView and unzip it or copy your existing Windows IrfanView folder to Linux. This is easier because the installer may need additional Windows DLLs to run.

If you want a software that is more OS independent then I would recommend [UFRaw](http://ufraw.sourceforge.net/). Use it either on its own or in conjunction with [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/)

Comment: I think this is a better solution then mine, IrfanView can do a lot more than these conversions.

Comment: Well, that's up to OP to judge :)

Comment: IrfanView 4.57 with installed plugins is unable to open NEF from Nikon D800 on Ubuntu 20.10. It's too bad because I've been using IrfanView on Windows for years.

Answer (score 28):

One solution, on Ubuntu, would be to use `dcraw` to convert NEF to PBM, and `pnmtopng` to convert PBM to png. So, open a terminal and run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install netpbm dcraw
```

I don't have any .NEF images to test this, but according to [this page](http://www.noah.org/wiki/ImageMagick), you can do:

> Convert all NEF images to PNG:
>
> ```
> dcraw -c -w input.NEF | pnmtopng > output.png
> ```
>
> To convert an entire directory:
>
> ```
> for filename in *.NEF ; do dcraw -c -w "$filename" | pnmtopng > "$filename.png" ; done
> ```

Probably the best tool around for all your batch image processing needs, however, is [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). It's free, open source, cross platform and can do just about everything you can think of including resizing, cropping, managing transparancy, montage and converting between most image formats under the sun. It would have been my first choice, but I found some (older) posts claiming that it did not work with NEF. Still, their website says it [does](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php), so you should try it out and in any case, it is really worth learning. Install it on Ubuntu with:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

To convert a single .NEF:

```
convert foo.NEF foo.jpg
```

To convert all .NEF files in the current directory (**will overwrite the originals**):

```
mogrify -format jpg *.NEF
```

To do the same but keeping the original files, run `convert` in a loop:

```
for img in *.NEF; do convert "$img" "$img.jpg"; done
```

Comment: You might need to install `ufraw-batch` first. (I had to `sudo apt-get install ufraw-batch` to make mogrify work)

Comment: Oh and `mogrify -format jpg *.NEF` does not overwrite the originals

Comment: This is great! If I want to run "mogrify -format jpg *.NEF" also for NEFs in subdirectories, how would the bash script look like? Thanks.

Comment: @Regmi try `find . -name "*.NEF" -exec mogrify -format jpg {} +`.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for, I didn't want to have to install WINE in addition to some windows program! Just wanted to run it as a single command the linux way.  Thanks again!

Comment: Just in case anyone else is looking into this, please note @Clash is incorrect, `mogrify` *will* overwrite your originals (in other words, @terdon had it right to begin with).

From the mogrify man page:
`NAME
       mogrify  - resize an image, blur, crop, despeckle, dither, draw on, flip, join, re-sample, and much more. Mogrify overwrites the
       original image file, whereas, convert(1) writes to a different image file.
`

Answer (score 11):

If you do end up using `ImageMagick`, then I recommend using `xargs` if you've actually got thousands of images to convert rather than using a `for` loop. That way, you can easily bump up the parallelism:

```
# Runs these conversions serially
ls *.NEF | sed 's#.NEF##' | xargs -I^ convert ^.NEF ^.jpg

# Runs these conversions with 8 different processes
ls *.NEF | sed 's#.NEF##' | xargs -P8 -I^ convert ^.NEF ^.jpg
```

Answer (score 3):

Using GNU Parallel:

```
parallel convert {} {.}.jpg ::: *NEF
```

Deals correctly with filenames containing ', " and space.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [NEFtoJPG](http://www.neftojpg.com/). Its free and can do batch processing.

Comment: Unfortunately it's for Windows only

Comment: @NickolayKondratenko How about Wine?

Comment: If to choose between native app and wine I'd choose native one

Comment: It's very very very slow.

Answer (score 2):

This [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283791/182655) was given by [alexpotato](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/39716/alexpotato) and [dawid-drozd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/43916/dawid-drozd) at *Unix & Linux* to [Converting .NEF to .JPG](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/226900/182655). It is not my own solution. Please give the credit to them.

The program `ufraw-batch` does the job. After installing the program, do:

```
ufraw-batch --out-type jpeg *
```

Answer (score 0):

i know this is a old question but recently **Nikon** released a **free** version of

[Nikon Capture NX-D](http://nikonimglib.com/ncnxd/)

imho the best way to go

Comment: 340MB for a converter?! That's insane.

Comment: It's more powerful than just converting and the result has excellent quality (compared to irfanview with plugin)